# How to set and get Cookies data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

i have an option of multiple image upload in my web .at this time i am getting their src after uploading to server using jquery and send their src to other pages way a get method of form .this is pretty illogical  and i can only send images from main page to other pages.

i want to store their sources on to the cookies so each page check cookies first and load images from server . no need to go to main page every time for uploading images

i know this is a basic question  but please guide me with an example that how can i do this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

To set the cookies use [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

```
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("name", "Hello World", time() - 3600);
```

To get the cookies use [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

```
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["name"]) . '!';
```

Answer (score 0):

**using javascript**

```
set cookie
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
     exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
     var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
     document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

setCookie('TestCookie',1,1);

delete cookie
function deleteCookie(name) {
    cocument.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};

deleteCookie('TestCookie');
```

**using PHP**

```
set cookie
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>

delete cookie
<?php
// set the expiration date to one hour ago
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("TestCookie", "", time() - 3600, "/~rasmus/", "example.com", 1);
?>
```